# How to write directy math symbolic equition in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

is there a way to enter math formulas symbolically directly into tkinter?
For example, if I press the R button on the keyboard, the symbol √ should be written [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViwlZ.png)directly in the text input field instead of R ???

[like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViwlZ.png)

Comment: i think there is latex for tkinter, and you can always use unicode

Comment: can you help me how to use it directtly???

Comment: @AilaqiBarca advice: use search engines and find tutorials or documentation, you currently don't have a very specific issue so I will have to vote to close this, also you haven't provided what you have tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Take a look on [Writing mathematical expressions](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html#writing-mathematical-expressions) using `matplotlib`.

Comment: You would probably have to use `bind()` to insert other characters when a key is pressed.